# What is the column space for ridge regression?

Tags: matrix, ridge-regression, linear-algebra

In OLS, our $\hat{y}$ lies in the subspace spanned by the columns of $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$.

For ridge regression, what subspace does $\hat{y}$ lie in? What spans this subspace?

I know that
$$
\hat{\beta}_{OLS} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty \\
\hat{\beta}_{ridge} = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty \\
$$

but in terms of vector spaces, I am not sure where $\hat{y}_{ridge}$ lies.

Comment: Doesn't it just lie in the same subspace? The difference is that now the residual vector $y - \hat{y}$ is no longer orthogonal? For both OLS and Ridge, you have $\hat{y} = X\hat{\beta}$. So for both cases, $\hat{y}$ is a linear combination of the columns of $X$.

Comment: By orthogonal ^ I mean orthogonal to the column space of X.

Comment: yeah for _any_ $\beta$, the prediction $X \beta$ is in the subspace spanned by the column space of $X$.